# How to slice all integers in a list?

Tags: python, list, integer, slice

Can anyone tell me how to slice through a list of varying types to include only integers?

A list such as this:

```
c = [32.45, 'foo', 3, 4, 'fare', True, 3.9871]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be

```
c = [32.45, 'foo', 3, 4, 'fare', True, 3.9871]
print (c)
d = [val for val in c if type(val) is int]
print (d)
```

Result:

```
[32.45, 'foo', 3, 4, 'fare', True, 3.9871]
[3, 4]
```

You need `type` here, not `isinstance` because that includes `True`.